# ElasticSearch NEST C# ApiCall is always the same and values on documents property are wierd

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm new to ElasticSearch. Can someone explain to me why I'm always getting Api call like this:

"/pokemon/_search?typed_keys=true"

Why this Nest NuGet package doesn't change api call to ElasticSearch even when I am creating queries in C# like this

```
        ISearchResponse<Pokemon> results;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
        {
            results = _client.Search<Pokemon>(s => s.Index("Pokemon")
                .Query(q => q
                    .Term(t => t
                        .Field(f => f.Id)
                        .Value(query)
                    )
                )
            );
        }
        else
        {
            results = _client.Search<Pokemon>(s => s.Index("Pokemon")
                .Query(q => 
                    q.MatchAll()
                )
            );
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

The results from api call "/pokemon/_search?typed_keys=true" aren't what I want to get

Do I need to create my own HttpClient API?

[image: What is wrong here?]

At the end in "documents" property, I don't receive my collection of Pokémon object but something else

So, I don't know what code to write when a tutorial that I am using has the same code just different example of data

Comment: The actual query is in the body and not in some Query Parameters. You have to look there.

Comment: Right now, I am giving up. I am using HttpClient and I receiving what I need. Maybe later I will find better tutorial with NEST with code that works also on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I must say that this "Nest" library is confusing but all that problems are simple to resolve

The problem was that client tried to deserialize camelCased JSON objects keys to the POCO properties and is strict for casting.

Solution: When creating ES client add settings property DefaultFieldNameInferrer on ConnectionSettings.

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool).DefaultIndex("pokemons");
settings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

I was so confused by the result of this app that I thought it was querying ElasticSearch badly and the HTTP GET call address is the culprit